# Handle subsets of data frames in R

Tags: r, vector

I have the following dataset with two columns c1 and c2:

```
"c1""c2"
1  NA
1  NA
1  NA
1  Low
2  NA
2  NA
2  High
3  Low
3  NA
3  NA
3  High
4  NA
4  High
4  NA
4  Low
```

What I would like to have is, based on the first column presenting different participants (same participant = same number):

- remove all NAs until the first non-NA
- after the first non-NA, copy that value to all the subsequent participant lines and overwrite any NA, until the next participant comes up

My output here would be:

```
1 Low
2 High
3 Low
3 Low
3 Low
3 Low
4 High
4 High
4 High
```

Does that make sense ? If yes, what could I do without using a for-loop ? Thanks for any help and I'm not sure about a good title for this either.
Regards !

Comment: "copy the value" means: Please also overwrite subsequent NAs

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'c1', we get the index of first non-NA element in 'c2'.  subset the 'c2' based on 'i1' and replicate it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, {
          i1 <- which.max(!is.na(c2))
           .(c2 = rep(c2[i1], .N-i1+1))} , by = c1]
#   c1   c2
#1:  1  Low
#2:  2 High
#3:  3  Low
#4:  3  Low
#5:  3  Low
#6:  3  Low
#7:  4 High
#8:  4 High
#9:  4 High
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), c2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Low", NA, NA, "High", 
"Low", NA, NA, "High", NA, "High", NA, "Low")), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```